# Local mirror of a local git clone

Tags: git

I have a large file that can not be pushed to `github` and need to do surgery on my local clone. The recommended approach is to use the `BFG` tool https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/: and this requires a local mirror of a *remote* repo.   So how can I make a mirror of the *local* repo in order to use that tool?

Note that the following question that has a similar title is actually mostly unrelated since it is not dealing with mirroring a local clone: 
 [Git local mirror and repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980793/git-local-mirror-and-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"remote" here doesn't mean it has to be on another machine, it just means it's not your current "local" clone of the repository. Git remotes don't require a network or server, you can clone a directory.

```
git clone /path/to/your/repo
```

See the ["Working With Remotes"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) chapter of Pro Git for more.

---

That said, the BFG docs are referring to your existing clone of your Github repository. You don't need to make another clone.

HOWEVER, you might want to make a backup of your clone in case things go wrong. Simply copy the directory. While it's possible to undo what BFG does, it's much simpler to restore from a backup in case things go wrong.

Comment: thx: i was uncertain if a simple FQP would represent a git url.